# How to zoom on a map using d3 on canvas?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

Some background:
I have plotted a map and about 35k circles on it with zoom and tooltips working fine on SVG. However, due to the amount of circles that need to be drawn (and may be not the best written code; i'm a beginner) I see performance issues while getting the page to run. 
And so, I wanted to try out the same page on a canvas to improve performance.

Problem:
I got the map itself working on canvas but I have been trying to add the zoom feature but in vain. Any help in getting this fixed will be greatly appreciated.

Sample with SVG - https://bl.ocks.org/sharad-vm/af74ae5932de1bcf5a39b0f3f849d847

The code I have for Canvas is as below:

```
        //Width and height
        var w = 700;
        var h = 600;

          //Create Canvas element
        var canvas = d3.select('#map')
                      .append('canvas')
                      .attr('width', w)
                      .attr('height', h);

        var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

        //Define map projection
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                               .translate([w/2, h/1.72])
                               .scale([100]);


        //Define path generator
        var path = d3.geo.path()
                         .projection(projection)
                         .context(context);

        var init = 0;

        canvas.call(zoom);

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .translate([0, 0])
                    .scale(1)
                    .scaleExtent([1, 30])
                    .on("zoom", zoomed);

        //function to zoom
        function zoomed() {
         context.save();
         context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
         context.translate(d3.event.transform.x, d3.event.transform.y);
         context.scale(d3.event.transform.k, d3.event.transform.k);
         draw();
         context.restore();
         };

        draw();  

        //Load in GeoJSON data
        function draw() {
          ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using projections the secret to get the zoom working is to transform the projection itself. For your example you can just adjust your projection before redrawing with something like:

`projection.translate([w/2 + d3.event.transform.x, h/1.72 + d3.event.transform.y])
    .scale([100*d3.event.transform.k]);`

Another option is to scale the canvas itself, [like in this example I made](http://blockbuilder.org/john-guerra/05fafb55db94775db6b40ba62aa02772)